# Qt integrating external -- ExcelFormat library inside -- QT project

Tags: qt, export-to-excel

I want to `export` some text of the table view to the excel sheet using `ExcelFormat library` .
I have a button which when pressed will export my data to `xls` file.

How can i include this external library source code (`ExcelFormat_src`) inside the `QT project` so that i can use this library in my project `?`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library

I am working on `Windows-7` installed on my PC.

Do i need `MS-office excel 2007` for this `?`

Please guide me if some one have done this before.

Edit :
My project file :---

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = ExcelFormatLibrary
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ExcelFormat.cpp \
    BasicExcel.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ExcelFormat.h \
    BasicExcel.hpp
```

My main.cpp file :----

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include "ExcelFormat.h"

using namespace ExcelFormat;


#ifdef _WIN32

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#else // _WIN32

#define FW_NORMAL   400
#define FW_BOLD     700

#endif // _WIN32


static void example1(const char* path)
{
    BasicExcel xls;

     // create sheet 1 and get the associated BasicExcelWorksheet pointer
    xls.New(1);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);


     // Create a table containing an header row in bold and four rows below.

    ExcelFont font_bold;
    font_bold._weight = FW_BOLD; // 700

    CellFormat fmt_bold(fmt_mgr);
    fmt_bold.set_font(font_bold);

    int col, row = 0;

    for(col=0; col<10; ++col) {
        BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(row, col);

        cell->Set("TITLE");
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_bold);
    }

    while(++row < 4) {
        for(int col=0; col<10; ++col)
            sheet->Cell(row, col)->Set("text");
    }


    ++row;

    ExcelFont font_red_bold;
    font_red_bold._weight = FW_BOLD;
    font_red_bold._color_index = EGA_RED;

    CellFormat fmt_red_bold(fmt_mgr, font_red_bold);
    fmt_red_bold.set_color1(COLOR1_PAT_SOLID);          // solid background
    fmt_red_bold.set_color2(MAKE_COLOR2(EGA_BLUE,0));   // blue background

    CellFormat fmt_green(fmt_mgr, ExcelFont().set_color_index(EGA_GREEN));

    for(col=0; col<10; ++col) {
        BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(row, col);

        cell->Set("xxx");
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_red_bold);

        cell = sheet->Cell(row, ++col);
        cell->Set("yyy");
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_green);
    }


    xls.SaveAs(path);
}


static void example2(const char* path)
{
    BasicExcel xls;

     // create sheet 1 and get the associated BasicExcelWorksheet pointer
    xls.New(1);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);

    ExcelFont font_header;
    font_header.set_weight(FW_BOLD);
    font_header.set_underline_type(EXCEL_UNDERLINE_SINGLE);
    font_header.set_font_name(L"Times New Roman");
    font_header.set_color_index(EGA_BLUE);
    font_header._options = EXCEL_FONT_STRUCK_OUT;

    CellFormat fmt_header(fmt_mgr, font_header);
    fmt_header.set_rotation(30); // rotate the header cell text 30° to the left

    int row = 0;

    for(int col=0; col<10; ++col) {
        BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(row, col);

        cell->Set("TITLE");
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_header);
    }

    char buffer[100];

    while(++row < 10) {
        for(int col=0; col<10; ++col) {
            sprintf(buffer, "text %d/%d", row, col);

            sheet->Cell(row, col)->Set(buffer);
        }
    }

    xls.SaveAs(path);
}


static void example3(const char* path)
{
    BasicExcel xls;

     // create sheet 1 and get the associated BasicExcelWorksheet pointer
    xls.New(1);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);
    CellFormat fmt(fmt_mgr);
    BasicExcelCell* cell;


     // row 1

    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_INTEGER);
    cell = sheet->Cell(0, 0);
    cell->Set(1.);
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);

    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_DECIMAL);
    cell = sheet->Cell(0, 1);
    cell->Set(2.);
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);

    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_DATE);
    fmt.set_font(ExcelFont().set_weight(FW_BOLD));
    cell = sheet->Cell(0, 2);
    cell->Set("03.03.2000");
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);


     // row 2

    fmt.set_font(ExcelFont().set_weight(FW_NORMAL));
    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_GENERAL);
    cell = sheet->Cell(1, 0);
    cell->Set("normal");
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);

    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_TEXT);
    cell = sheet->Cell(1, 1);
    cell->Set("Text");
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);

    fmt.set_format_string(XLS_FORMAT_GENERAL);
    fmt.set_font(ExcelFont().set_weight(FW_BOLD));
    cell = sheet->Cell(1, 2);
    cell->Set("bold");
    cell->SetFormat(fmt);


    xls.SaveAs(path);
}


static void example_read_write(const char* from, const char* to)
{
    cout << "read " << from << endl;
    BasicExcel xls(from);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    CellFormat fmt_general(fmt_mgr);

    fmt_general.set_format_string("0.000");

    for(int y=0; y<2; ++y) {
        for(int x=0; x<2; ++x) {
            cout << y << "/" << x;

            BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(y, x);

            CellFormat fmt(fmt_mgr, cell);

//          cout << " - xf_idx=" << cell->GetXFormatIdx();

            const Workbook::Font& font = fmt_mgr.get_font(fmt);
            string font_name = stringFromSmallString(font.name_);
            cout << "  font name: " << font_name;

            const wstring& fmt_string = fmt.get_format_string();
            cout << "  format: " << narrow_string(fmt_string);

            cell->SetFormat(fmt_general);

            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "write: " << from << endl;
    xls.SaveAs(to);
}


static void example4(const char* path)
{
    BasicExcel xls;

    xls.New(1);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);

    char buffer[100];
    int i = 0;

    for(int row=0; row<8; ++row) {
        int color = i++;
        int height = 100 * i;

        sprintf(buffer, "Times New Roman %d", height/20);

        ExcelFont font;
        font.set_color_index(color);
        font.set_height(height);
        font.set_font_name(L"Times New Roman");

        CellFormat fmt(fmt_mgr, font);
        fmt.set_background(MAKE_COLOR2(EGA_MAGENTA,0)); // solid magenta background

        BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(row, 0);
        cell->Set(buffer);
        cell->SetFormat(fmt);
    }

    xls.SaveAs(path);
}


static void copy_sheet(const char* from, const char* to)
{
    BasicExcel xls;

    xls.Load(from);
    xls.SaveAs(to);
}


static void write_big_sheet(const char* path, const int row_max, const int col_max)
{
    BasicExcel xls;
    char buffer[16];

     // create sheet 1 and get the associated BasicExcelWorksheet pointer
    xls.New(1);
    BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = xls.GetWorksheet(0);

    XLSFormatManager fmt_mgr(xls);


     // Create a table containing header row and column in bold.

    ExcelFont font_bold;
    font_bold._weight = FW_BOLD; // 700

    CellFormat fmt_bold(fmt_mgr);
    fmt_bold.set_font(font_bold);

    int col, row;

    BasicExcelCell* cell = sheet->Cell(0, 0);
    cell->Set("Row / Column");
    cell->SetFormat(fmt_bold);

    for(col=1; col<=col_max; ++col) {
        cell = sheet->Cell(0, col);

        sprintf(buffer, "Column %d", col);
        cell->Set(buffer);
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_bold);
    }

    for(row=1; row<=row_max; ++row) {
        cell = sheet->Cell(row, 0);

        sprintf(buffer, "Row %d", row);
        cell->Set(buffer);
        cell->SetFormat(fmt_bold);
    }

    for(row=1; row<=row_max; ++row) {
        for(int col=1; col<=col_max; ++col) {
            sprintf(buffer, "%d / %d", row, col);

            sheet->Cell(row, col)->Set(buffer);
        }
    }

    xls.SaveAs(path);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

#ifdef _MSC_VER
     // detect memory leaks
//  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(0)|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif


     // call example1()
    example1("example1.xls");

     // call example2()
    example2("example2.xls");

     // call example3()
    example3("example3.xls");

     // dump out cell contents of example3.xls and write modified to example3-out.xls
    example_read_write("example3.xls", "example3-out.xls");

     // call example4()
    example4("example4.xls");

     // create a table containing 500 x 100 cells
    write_big_sheet("big-example.xls", 500, 100);


#ifdef _WIN32
     // open the output files in Excel
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "example1.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "example2.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "example3.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "example3.out.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "example4.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
    ShellExecute(0, NULL, "big-example.xls", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
#endif

    return 0;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please suggest on this question.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need MS-Office. Write the files BasicExcel.[h, cpp] and ExcelFormat.[h, cpp] to your *.pro file. Have a look on Examples.cpp in the ExcelForma Project.

Comment: Might be worth including a link to the project you refer to.

Comment: I have already added headers to the project. But getting the same error. I have edited my main post to include the source code. Please suggest on it.